# I want to create an PDF using standard library from android. After creation I want to save it using an intent

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, android-intent, permissions

I want to create an app that is not using any system permissions. And I found out, that using Intent#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT can create and save files without asking for permissions in Manifest.

But I do not have a clue how to

Option 1 - hand over the created file from Intent to PdfDocument so that I can write my PDF and save it later.

OR

Option 2 - create my PDF first and hand it over to Intent instead of Document.writeTo(storage)

And yes, by now I cannot provide any code because it is too rough and inconsistent. :-(

Can somebody of you give me a hint or code snippet for that?

Comment: `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` gives you a `Uri` to the document. Use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` to the location identified by the `Uri`. Pass that `OutputStream` to `writeTo()` on your `PdfDocument`.

Comment: Thanks... sometimes it is so easy :-)